# Use Apache to load a page sitting on a different server with the same URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have a situation where ideally we would like a user to access a page on our site at a URL such as https://example.com/path/to/page. However, the HTML to render that page is sitting on an entirely different server (S3 to be exact) that we have control over, and we would like to render that page for that URL without redirecting (i.e. changing the URL itself).

I took a brief look at the Apache mod_proxy module, but it doesn't seem to do the job as we just get 500 or 404 errors. Here is an example entry from our .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
RewriteRule "/path/to/page/(.*)$" "https://bucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/page/$1" [P]
</IfModule>
```

Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the proxy module itself since apparently you want to map _all_ content below that path to that other server, but rely on the module embedded in the rewriting module?

Comment: I'd love to use whatever is recommended and designed for the job. Its a matter of figuring out how. I am by no means an Apache configuration expert, I know just enough to get by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you stumble over the fact that you are using an absolute path inside a dynamic cohnfiguration files `RewriteRule`. Have a try with that instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "/?path/to/page/(.*)$" "https://bucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/page/$1" [P]
```

That slightly modified will work in dynamic configuration files *and* in the real http servers host configuration.

---

But as mentioned in the comment I wonder why you should not be able to use the proxy module directly to simplify things. You'd have to do that in in http servers host configuration though, this is not possible in dynamic configuration files:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass "/path/to/page/" "https://bucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/page/"
ProxyPassReverse "/path/to/page/" "https://bucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/page/"
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Using the mod_proxy directives inside the apache config file causes a 504 error. Apache error logs are also not showing any errors messages so debugging this has become a little tricky.

Comment: http status 504 means "Gateway timeout", so most likely your request _is_ getting proxied, but the internal request to the amazon target does not receive any reply.

Comment: I seem to have now gotten the requests to try and connect, however I keep getting the following errors. Bearing in mind this is running on Ubuntu 14.04:

[Mon Mar 13 12:36:32.306225 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1241] [client x.x.x.x:43422] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: bucketname.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Same general issue: apache tries to make the internal request to amazon but fails to do so. I suggest you try to make the same request from the system that http server operates on. You can use a command line http client or browser for that. Maybe some network topology issue?

Comment: I realised the issue. I was directing to https when I had not yet setup https with the required bucket. Once I reverted to http it all worked a treat. Busy working on implementing https so I can switch it back to that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey, glad to hear that. Have fun!